# celery seems to sleep and not working

Tags: django, celery, flower

I am using celery and flower to perform a periodic task.
The problem is that sometimes the tasks are not performed at the determined time and when I restart celery in the shell, the delayed tasks starts to be done.
Do you know what is the problem and how can I solve it?

Comment: How do you expect people to help you without posting any code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that my tasks are blocked because I did not apply any soft time limit